# Unique string table in SQL and replacing index values with string values during query

Tags: sql, indexing, unique

I'm working on an old SQL Server database that has several tables that look like the following:

```
|-------------|-----------|-------|------------|------------|-----|
| MachineName | AlarmName | Event | AlarmValue | SampleTime | ... |
|-------------|-----------|-------|------------|------------|-----|
| 3           | 180       | 8     | 6.780      | 2014-02-24 |     |
| 9           | 67        | 8     | 1.45       | 2014-02-25 |     |
| ...         |           |       |            |            |     |
|-------------|-----------|-------|------------|------------|-----|
```

There is a separate table in the database that only contains unique strings, as well as the index for each unique string. The unique string table looks like this:

```
|----------|--------------------------------|
| Id       | String                         |
|----------|--------------------------------|
| 3        | MyMachine                      |
| ...      |                                |
| 8        | High CPU Usage                 |
| ...      |                                |
| 67       | 404 Error                      |
| ...      |                                |
|----------|--------------------------------|
```

Thus, when we want to get something out of the database, we get the respective rows out, then lookup each missing string based on the index value.

**What I'm hoping to do is to replace all of the string indexes with the actual values in a single query without having to do post-processing on the query result.**

However, I can't figure out how to do this in a single query. Do I need to use multiple JOINs? I've only been able to figure out how to replace a single value by doing something like -

```
SELECT UniqueString.String AS "MachineName" FROM UniqueString 
JOIN Alarm ON Alarm.MachineName = UniqueString.Id
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are AlarmName and Event also indexes into UniqueString?

Comment: @albe - Yes, all values that aren't numerical or DateTime are stored as a unique string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do multiple joins to the UniqueStrings table, but change the order to start with the table you are reporting on and use unique aliases for the joined table. Something like:

```
SELECT MN.String AS 'MachineName', AN.String as 'AlarmName'  FROM Alarm A 
  JOIN UniqueString MN ON A.MachineName = MN.Id
  JOIN UniqueString AN ON A.AlarmName = AN.Id
```

etc for any other columns

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. I don't use JDBC, but a quick search showed this article on SO (and some others) that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440429/java-jdbc-sql-error-index-out-of-range It's likely in your calling params